# How to iterate the List in Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am having one property called Students which is of type `List<Student>`.

In reflection i can get the value of Students Property.

Now the problem is How to iterate the List of Students.

I need to check whether StudentID [ some value ] is in that collection.

```
var collection = studentPro.GetValue(studentObj,null);

//I need to iterate like this,

foreach(var item in collection)
{
     if(item.StudentID == 33)
         //Do stuff
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need to **cast** it:

```
var collection = (List<Student>) studentPro.GetValue(studentObj,null);
```

The value returned to you and stored in `var` is of type `object`. So you need to cast it to `List<Student>` first, before trying looping through it.

### RANT

That is why I *personally* do not like `var`, it hides the type - unless in VS you hover on it. If it was a declared with type `object` it was immediately obvious that we cannot iterate through it.

---

## UPDATE

> Yes its good. But casting should be
>   done with reflection. In reflection we
>   dont know the type of List. We dont
>   know the actual type of the studentObj

In order to do that, you can cast to `IEnumerable`:

```
var collection = (IEnumerable) studentPro.GetValue(studentObj,null);
```

Comment: Yes its good. But casting should be done with reflection. In reflection we dont know the type of List<?>. We dont know the actual type of the studentObj.

Comment: While trying this i am getting an error - Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments.

Comment: Jagan - The error you posted is obvious it requires a type.  Furthermore you shouldn't be using the method your using if you don't understand how to do it ( given the fact your code conceptionally correct all except for the fact you forgot to cast stuff ).

Comment: Ok. In reflection, Just consider I am having one Object but dont the type of it. If that object is Collection i need to iterate it and need to print all values.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
IEnumerable<Student> collection = (IEnumerable<Student>)studentPro.GetValue(studentObj,null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have suggested casting to List but I will assume that this won't work for you... if you had access to the Student class, you wouldn't be using reflection to begin with.  So instead, just cast to IEnumerable and then inside your loop, you'll have to use reflection again to access whatever properties you want off of each item in the collection.

`var collection = (IEnumerable)studentPro.GetValue(studentObj,null)`

Comment: While trying this i am getting an error - Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: try (System.Collections.IEnumerable)

Comment: That would solve his problem. Although I question is inability to solve such a simple problem himself.  He really shouldn't even be using a generic collection.

Answer (score 1):

The way you tried is, is the right one. You just need to fix your code and cast the return value from `GetValue`:

```
var collection = (List<Student>)studentPro.GetValue(studentObj,null);

foreach(var item in collection)
{
     if(item.StudentID == 33)
         //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like below to create a POCO object out of your proxy object. Please note that I am relying on use of XMLIgnore attribute to break circular references

```
static object DeepCopy(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            Type t = obj.GetType();

            object objCopy = Activator.CreateInstance(targetType);

            Type copyType = targetType;

            var props =
                t.GetProperties();

                    //.Where(x => x.PropertyType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlIgnoreAttribute), false).Length == 0);
            foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
            {
                var targetProperty = copyType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name == propertyInfo.Name).First();

                if (targetProperty.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlIgnoreAttribute), false).Length > 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsClass)
                {
                    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetInterface("IList", true)!=null)
                    {
                        var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(targetProperty.PropertyType);

                        targetProperty.SetValue(objCopy,list);

                        var sourceList = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj) as IList;

                        foreach (var o in sourceList)
                        {
                            list.Add(DeepCopy(o, targetProperty.PropertyType.UnderlyingSystemType.GenericTypeArguments[0]));
                        }

                    }
                    else if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    {
                        targetProperty.SetValue(objCopy, propertyInfo.GetValue(obj));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        targetProperty.SetValue(objCopy, DeepCopy(propertyInfo.GetValue(obj), targetProperty.PropertyType));
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    targetProperty.SetValue(objCopy,propertyInfo.GetValue(obj));
                }
            }

            return objCopy;

        }
        return null;
    }

    class MyDbContext:DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext():base(@"Server=(LocalDb)\v12.0;Trusted_Connection=True;")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Table1> Table1s { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Table2> Table2s { get; set; }

}

public class Table1
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    virtual public List<Table2> Table2s { get; set; }
}


public class Table2
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    virtual public Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
}
```