# Problem with IEnumerable in Reflection

Tags: c#, ienumerable

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to iterate the List in Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949688/how-to-iterate-the-list-in-reflection)
>   [Problem with IEnumerable in Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950222/problem-with-ienumerable-in-reflection)

Hi,

I am facing a problem while Iterating the List in reflection.

```
var item = property.GetValue(obj,null); // We dont know the type of obj as it is in Reflection.

foreach(var value in (item as IEnumerable))
 {
   //Do stuff
  }
```

If i do this i will get the error like

Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' requires 1 type arguments

Please help me.

Comment: you need cast to `IEnumerable<T>` not IEnumerable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a difference between the type `IEnumerable` and the generic type `IEnumerable<T>`. Currently it thinks you mean the generic one as you've included the namespace `System.Collections.Generic`; The error message is complaining because you've not written the `IEnumerable<T>` generic type correctly.

The non-generic `IEnumerable` type is declared in the `System.Collections` namespace, so add a reference to it. (`using System.Collections;`).

If you did mean to use the generic type then you should have something like this: `foreach(var value in (item as IEnumerable<string>))` where string is the type of object `item` enumerates over.

See [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) and [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) as well as this [information about generic types.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: posted my own answer but yours is more complete. +1

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you already asked this question. This instance though is having a slightly different issue. You are getting a compiler error because you are including System.Collections.Generic namespace in your source file (top using clauses). That namespace contains the generic version of IEnumerable -> `IEnumerable<T>`. Your cast fails because of that. If you want to use IEnumerable add
"`using System.Collections`".